# rabbitmq-server-3.8.9 unable to start server

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running rabbitmq-server-3.8.9 on fedora 29 machine with erlang 24. I am getting the following error.

sudo ./rabbitmq-server start
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{rabbit_misc,report_default_thread_pool_size,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Comment: Did you used the RPM based installer ...it appears that it may not be officially supported on Fedora 29 . What i could find that v 3.6.3 is supported through Fedora 20 to 30

Comment: why is this error happening. Is it due to some setup issue.